# phpBB session integration & fatal error

Tags: php, session, integration, phpbb

I have a website which I built from scratch, obviously located in my root folder.

Inside my root folder I have a directory names "forum" which has my phpBB 3.0.8 installation inside of it.

All I want to do is display a currently logged in user's avatar, name, and message count on my website's index.

I know that a session must first be started. I found this website and followed it step by step.
http://www.3cc.org/blog/2010/03/integrating-your-existing-site-into-phpbb3/

The ONLY thing that I changed was

`$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : 'change_this_to_phpbb_dir';`

to

`$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : './forum';`

When I created my test page, I get

> Fatal error: Call to a member function session_begin() on a non-object in /data/25/2/25/137/2514626/user/2754604/htdocs/alpha/phpbb.php on line 7

Line 7 being `$user->session_begin();`

I have read a million articles and forum posts with similar problems, but nothing has seemed to help. My phpBB forum can be found here: http://alphakravmagainternational.com/forum/

Please keep in mind that I'm a php / phpBB noob, so please try to include examples. Im still learning :)

Thank you

phpbb.php file:

```
<?php
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : './forum';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
// Start session management
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
$user->setup();
?>
```

Comment: Where did you make this only change? Inside a file within phpBB or within a file outside phpBB (one on your site you wish to be able to report phpBB user information)? What is the output if you place the line `var_dump($phpbb_root_path);` after the line you modified?

Comment: Please show us some more of phpbb.php. In particular, I'm interested to see when `$user` is being defined.

Comment: I have edited the original post to include my phpbb.php file. This code would be included on my website's index, which is where I would like the information to display.

PhpMyCoder: the output after adding that line was as follows: 
`string(7) "./forum" 
Fatal error: Call to a member function session_begin() on a non-object in /data/25/2/25/137/2514626/user/2754604/htdocs/alpha/phpbb.php on line 8`

Comment: Change `'./forum'` in line 3 into `'./forum/'`. If that fails, use `require` instead of `include` in line 5 and post the resulting error here.

Comment: Amazing how that one little / makes all of the difference. It works, now and I can't thank you enough for your help. I actually feel embarrassed i didn't try that sooner. Thank you!

Comment: Now I have a different, but related issue. The website that I got the code from said to put it on every page I would like to display the info on. Once i did that, I logged into my websites index page no problem, but when I clicked to a different page it required me to log in again. Is there a way to fix this so I can log in once from any page and still be logged in on others?